# Increasing Imagicks max resolution

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have a client who allows customers to upload large files to manipulate for printing. The site's using Imagick to handle the image, however, when trying to set the max width and height, it wont go any higher than 16000. For example:

```
// This sets the max width to 20000px
php > Imagick::setResourceLimit(9, 20000);
php > echo $image->getResourceLimit(9);
16000

php > Imagick::setResourceLimit(9, 15000);
php > echo $image->getResourceLimit(9);
15000
```

Is this a limitation of the library or is there something else I need to be configuring?

Comment: set max file size in your php ini file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size answers your question

Comment: No, the max file size is 2048M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find your `policy.xml` for **ImageMagick** and uncomment and set up the lines that look like this:

```
<!-- <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/> -->
<!-- <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="10KP"/> -->
<!-- <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="10KP"/> -->
```

You should be able to find the file with:

```
identify -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH
```

**Sample Output**

```
CONFIGURE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-10/etc/ImageMagick-7/
```

then append `policy.xml` to the end of that. So mine is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.8-10/etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml
```

If, for some reason you cannot find the `policy.xml` file by the method above, you can search for it the long (slower) way with:

```
find  /usr  /opt /  -name policy.xml
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've tried that, but it returns `Command 'identify' not found` and then suggests some imagemagick packages to install. However it's definitely installed and is listed in `phpinfo()`. I've also ran `apt-cache policy php-imagick` which has returned `php-imagick: Installed: 3.4.3-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, so it's installed, any ideas?

Comment: If you have v7 of **ImageMagick** installed and you didn't tick the box marked *"Install legacy commands"* when you installed, you need to prefix **ImageMagick** commands with the word `magick`, so try `magick identify ...`

Comment: Alternatively, you can find the file the long way with `find /usr  /opt  / -name policy.xml`

Comment: Found it! Thanks Mark!